# Apache mod-rewrite rule not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am facing issue with apache rewrite rule. i am expecting the below result

```
If URL is 
          http://www.mysite.co/testWeb/query1/guery2/3
Then Result 
          http://www.mysite.co/testWeb/index.html/#/query1/guery2/3
```

(index.html/# - has to be added in URL, it the path contains testWeb)

The rule i added is as follow

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^testWeb/(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/testWeb/index.html/#/$1 [L]
```

this rule is working fine in the rewrite rule online tester. But not in my apache. Any idea?

Comment: What is happening instead?

Comment: What does "is not working" actually mean?

Comment: Interpretation of `.htaccess` style files has to be enabled in the http servers host configuration first. Reason is that those files are really slowing the server down, so they are deactivated by default.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the Rule is creating a Redirect loop error on your server because your Regex pattern also matches the target url **/testweb/index.html** .

You need to use a negitive RewriteCond to prevent this .

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/testWeb/index\.html$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^testWeb/(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/testWeb/index.html/#/$1 [NC,L,NE]
```